# ngOnChange is not called when the parent updates the child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter, ngonchanges

i want to know how ngOnChanges callback works. so i have added it to observe changes in a prpoperty annotated with Input decorator as follows:

```
@Input() postsToAddToList: Post[] = [];
```

now, when I compile the code i add some values that causes change in the property annotated with @Input, but that does not cause the the ngOnChanges callback to be called and executed. please see logs shown in the screen-shot posted below.

i want to see the logs in the ngOnChanges displayed in the browser.
please let me know what prevents the ngOnChanges to be invoked and called correctly

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from './post-create/post-create.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'binding2';
  postsArray: Post[] = [];

  onReceiveSubmittedEvtEmitter(post: Post) {
    this.postsArray.push(post);
    console.log("onReceiveSubmittedEvtEmitter->: post.title: " + post.title);
    console.log("onReceiveSubmittedEvtEmitter->: post.content:" + post.content);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<app-post-create (onPostSubmittedEvtEmitter)="onReceiveSubmittedEvtEmitter($event)"></app-post-create>
<app-post-list [postsToAddToList]="postsArray"></app-post-list>
```

**post-list.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input,OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post-create/post-create.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  @Input() postsToAddToList: Post[] = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    for (let changedProperty in changes) {
      if (changes.hasOwnProperty(changedProperty)) {
        
        console.log("ngOnChanges->: changedProperty: " + changedProperty);
        console.log("ngOnChanges->: changedProperty:" + changedProperty);

        switch(changedProperty) {
          case 'postsToAddToList':
            console.log("ngOnChanges->: changes[changedProperty].previousValue: " + changes[changedProperty].previousValue);
            console.log("ngOnChanges->: changes[changedProperty].currentValue):" + changes[changedProperty].currentValue);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**post-list.component.html**:

```
<!-- post-list.component.html -->
<h3>List</h3>

<ng-container *ngIf="postsToAddToList.length; else elseTemplate">

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of postsToAddToList; let i = index">
            <h5>{{i+1}}) {{post.title}}</h5>
            <p>
                {{post.content}}
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>

</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        No Post Found!
    </div>

</ng-template>
```

**error screen-shot**:

[image]

Comment: `changes.postsToAddToList.currentValue` is enough instead of the loops

Comment: @AdarshMohan i tried it ..it does not solve the problem..i receive the same results

Comment: @LetsamrIt if my answer helped u. would u care to accept and upvote

Answer (score 1):

As u are using `push()` in your parent component, `ngOnChanges` will not be invoked in the child component. Instead of using `push()` you can reassign value to `postsToAddToList` every time there is a change in it.

Comment: to clarify: inputed objects are compared by reference, and since it's the same array, no change is detected